# Concat multiple columns to single columns with columname and values in Data Factory V2 Data Flow

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to concatenate selected column of excel sheet in seperate column using Azure Data Factory V2 data flow.

In data factory v2 using data flow we can create and update the existing columns using Derived Column Transformation.

I am having below excel file:

[image]

With Azure Data Factory data flow, I need to transform the file to below:

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible to achieve in Derived Columns data flow transformation

Answer (score 0):

You'll create E as a struct in a Derived Column. Create a new column in the Derived Column called "E" and then add 2 subcolumns. Assign the incoming field "C" to the new subcolumn C and incoming "D" to the subcolumn D.

[image]

Example video walk-thru: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAEh21NFgWQ

Comment: Thankyou Mark for the answer. If the subcolumn value is empty or null, then it is not considering in derived column. It is returning "E" as {} for empty subcolumn. The 'E' column should return {field1:null,field2:null}. File consist almost 320 subcolumns, is there a way where I can define the pattern for column names to add the subcolumn. Many thanks for your answer.